# DataTables warning: table id=coinsTable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

i am new to all these and i am overwhelmed. i am using a script and i get this error DataTables warning: table id=coinsTable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7. Here is my code please help me. I have tried replicating the steps on similar thread but it didnt work.

````
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.2/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>

@endpush
@push('js')
<script src="{{asset('/assets/admin/FileSaver.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/assets/admin/sweetalert2.all.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/assets/admin/jquery.blockUI.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/assets/admin/init.js')}}"></script>
@endpush

@push('js')
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    window.txTable = $('#coinsTable').dataTable({
        "order": [[ 5, 'asc' ]],
        "language": {
            "sDecimal":        ",",
            "sEmptyTable":     "{!! trans("admin.sEmptyTable")  !!}",
            "sInfo":           "{!! trans("admin.sInfo")  !!}",
            "sInfoEmpty":      "{!! trans("admin.sInfoEmpty")  !!}",
            "sInfoFiltered":   "{!! trans("admin.sInfoFiltered")  !!}",
            "sInfoPostFix":    "",
            "sInfoThousands":  ".",
            "sLengthMenu":     "{!! trans("admin.sLengthMenu")  !!}",
            "sLoadingRecords": "{!! trans("admin.sLoadingRecords")  !!}",
            "sProcessing":     "{!! trans("admin.sProcessing")  !!}",
            "sSearch":         "{!! trans("admin.sSearch")  !!}",
            "sZeroRecords":    "{!! trans("admin.sZeroRecords")  !!}",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst":    "{!! trans("admin.sFirst")  !!}",
                "sLast":     "{!! trans("admin.sLast")  !!}",
                "sNext":     "{!! trans("admin.sNext")  !!}",
                "sPrevious": "{!! trans("admin.sPrevious")  !!}"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending":  "{!! trans("admin.sSortAscending")  !!}",
                "sSortDescending": "{!! trans("admin.sSortDescending")  !!}"
            }
        },
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "{{$table}}",
            "type": "POST",
            'headers': { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'}
        },
        order: [[ 4, "desc" ]] ,
        scrollY: 400,
        scroller: {
            loadingIndicator: true
        },
        "drawCallback": function( ) {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        },
        type:'POST',
        columns: [
        
            {data: 'logo', name: 'logo', orderable:false},
            {data: 'name', name: 'name', orderable: true},
            {data: 'price', name: 'price', orderable: true},
            {data: 'change_pct', name: 'change_pct', orderable: true},
            {data: 'volume', name: 'volume'},
            {data: 'market_cap', name: 'market_cap'},
            {data: 'supply', name: 'supply'}
          
        ]
    });
});
</script>
@endpush```
````

Comment: I don't know what the heck this code is doing, but on the link you shared says this error occures when api response with code anything but 2xx. This means you can't get any data from the source. Try to catch the response of Ajax call. BTW, do you make this call to your laravel app or a third pary? If it's your Laravel app you need Sanctum, not csrf token. If it's 3rd party, you need a token they gave you, not csrf. So you have nothing to do with csrf token when you make an api call. You have probably receiving an invalid token error.

Comment: wow. its a third party